# append lists recursively in python

Tags: python, list, append

I have a loop. Everytime the loop runs, a new list is created. I want to add the all these lists together. My code is as follows:

```
while i < len(symbolslist):

    html_text = urllib.urlopen('my-url.com/'+symbolslist[i]).read()
    pattern = re.compile('<a target="_blank" href="(.+?)" rel="nofollow"')
    applink = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
    applink += applink
    i+=1
```

where applink is a list. However, with the current code I have, it only adds the last two lists together. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: applink = re.findall(pattern,htmltext) <...> applink += applink

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using `applink` as the variable name to store the list returned by `re.findall()` , hence you are ending up creating a new list everytime, instead of that use a different name and then extend applink to include the new list (or use `+=`).

Code -

```
applink = []
while i<len(symbolslist):

    url = "http://www.indeed.com/resumes/-/in-Singapore?co=SG&start="+str(symbolslist[i])
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<a target="_blank" href="(.+?)" rel="nofollow"'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    tempapplink = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print tempapplink
    applink += tempapplink
    i+=1
```